# Segmentation fault in sbrk(size_t)

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, malloc, sbrk

My program is very simple,

```
...
#define TO_INT(a) (*(int *)a)
void *pool_head;
void *pool_tail;
...

pool_head = sbrk(BUF_LENGTH);
if (pool_head == (void *)-1) {
    errno = ENOMEM;
    return pool_head;
}
pool_tail = sbrk(0);
TO_INT(pool_head)     = BUF_LENGTH * -1;
TO_INT((pool_tail - 3)) = BUF_LENGTH * -1;
```

When I debug it, It show:

`Program    received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.` at `TO_INT((pool_tail - 3)) = BUF_LENGTH * -1;`

the value of pool_tail & pool_head:

`pool_tail = 0x805a000`

`pool_head = 0x804a000`

How to solve it? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you cannot perform pointer arithmetic (`pool_tail - 3`) on `void *`.

Second, even if we allow it and treat `pool_tail` as `char *`, subtracting `pool_tail` by 3 does not give enough room to fit an `int`.

Comment: Cast it to `char *` first. Alternatively, you can simply do `*((int *)pool_tail - 1) = BUF_LENGTH * -1`. This will move `pool_tail` down by `sizeof(int)` (which is exactly 4) and thus ensure you have exactly enough room for one `int`.

Comment: @thlgood That's great! Keep in mind that you should mark an answer as the solution if it indeed solved your problem.